# Size in designer is not the same as real size. 25% difference

Tags: c#, winforms

`FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle

AutoScaleModel = None

MaximumSize/MinimumSize = 512,384

Size = 512,384`

I ran my program and used ALT+Print Screen to take a picture. PaintDotNet tells me the window is 640x480, or 25% larger than what it should be. Does anyone have any idea why the sizes do not match?

Comment: Have you enabled scaling (configured from control panel/Windows 10 settings app) on your system?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 and I don't think any scaling is enabled.